# Failure to display more than 2 variation next to the product title in the shopping cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I hope you answer

I used hook to display the variable next to the product name in the shopping cart

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_true' );
```

But if a product has more than 2 variables, it will only display the first 2 variables

true => product : variable 1 and variable 2 and variable 3

false => product : variable 1 and variable 2

path : /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variation-data-store-cpt.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Additional Methods
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/**
 * Generates a title with attribute information for a variation.
 * Products will get a title of the form "Name - Value, Value" or just "Name".
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param WC_Product $product Product object.
 * @return string
 */
protected function generate_product_title( $product ) {
    $attributes = (array) $product->get_attributes();

    // Do not include attributes if the product has 3+ attributes.
    $should_include_attributes = count( $attributes ) < 3;

    // Do not include attributes if an attribute name has 2+ words and the
    // product has multiple attributes.
    if ( $should_include_attributes && 1 < count( $attributes ) ) {
        foreach ( $attributes as $name => $value ) {
            if ( false !== strpos( $name, '-' ) ) {
                $should_include_attributes = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $should_include_attributes = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', $should_include_attributes, $product );
    $separator                 = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_attributes_separator', ' - ', $product );
    $title_base                = get_post_field( 'post_title', $product->get_parent_id() );
    $title_suffix              = $should_include_attributes ? wc_get_formatted_variation( $product, true, false ) : '';

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title', $title_suffix ? $title_base . $separator . $title_suffix : $title_base, $product, $title_base, $title_suffix );
}
```

I have noticed something : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wRnT.png)

if add gender-one -> Blue -> Short to cart, not show Short product title, I must create 2 variables to display the short

gender-one -> Blue -> Short

gender-one -> Blue -> Tall

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a function to return the title in a way you want and you'll have to hook that function with filter `woocommerce_product_variation_title`

basically, `wc_get_formatted_variation( $product, true, false )` this call returns the list of all attributes, you can make similar function to return only first 2 attributes and then you can use that function in your code.

Comment: I edited my question and added an image

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function to output all the attributes with an additional wrapper around them in a span. So I can hide their display on the cart page for example

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_title', 'vs_product_variation_title_callback', 10, 4);

function vs_product_variation_title_callback($variation_title, $product, $title_base, $title_suffix)
{
    $title_base  = get_post_field('post_title', $product->get_parent_id());
    $title_suffix =  wc_get_formatted_variation($product, true, false);

    return $title_base . '<span> - ' . $title_suffix . '</span>';
}
```

I have products with 3 variations and they are displayed when used `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_true' );`

Unfortunately, I don’t know what your problem might be, but I hope this custom function will help you, or those who, like me, stumble upon this issue, configure names with attributes